# Actors and Agents azure

Tags: azure, cloud

I am trying to find efficient way to store some temporary data in cloud.
I came across something call actors and agents. But not clear whether I can achieve it by using actors or agents. 
Is anyone have any suggestions or even good resource?

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like an interesting discussion, but it's not really a good fit for StackOverflow. Actor frameworks do exist and offer interesting capabilities, but your question doesn't share anything about your app. And even if it did, advice on using actor models will be opinion-based. Also, recommending specific tools (e.g. which actor model to use) is also off-topic.

Comment: not to mention it has nothing to do with azure.

Comment: I found something called Actor Framework for Windows Azure

Comment: https://actorfx.codeplex.com/

Comment: The most popular actor frameworks for Azure are Service Fabric, MS Orleans and TPL Dataflow.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to know more information about actor frameworks or are you looking for a way to efficiently store temp data in the cloud?

Comment: @Turowicz - Service Fabric is not an actor framework.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon, but it actually can run as an actor framework. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-choose-framework/

Comment: @Turowicz - Re-read the article. The Reliable Actor API is a service specifically tied to Service Fabric. You cannot just use the service fabric as an actor framework. The service fabric is not just a framework or a DLL you run. It's a platform.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you look at Azure Service Fabric for this. You can choose between reliable Actors and Services as a framework for your development.

https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-choose-framework/

I hope this helps
Niall Moran
@niallermoran

Comment: I don't know that service fabric is designed for temporary storage.... This is probably not a good answer to the question, which isn't really clear as it is.